# Tweet-deck-like applications for Reddit, Github and Stack Exchange

Tags: github, stack-exchange, reddit

I really like the tweet-deck model for seeing everything you are subscribed to in one place and with live updates.

Are there any applications like this for Reddit, GitHub and Stack Exchange?
(Or any other useful sites for that matter)

So far I found:

DeckHub (GitHub)

Reditr (Reddit)

Both seem to be desktop based.